# Selective Dependency Management for AWS SDK Versions in a Multi-Class Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, build, dependencies, aws-sdk

One of our library has both AWS SDK v1 and v2 classes, and thus both AWS SDK versions will be brought into the Lambda functions necessarily.

On our CodeCommit, there are still libraries using v1 version class and will be kept to using AWS SDK v1. (No plan to update them to AWS SDK v2 at the time)

Their dependencies needs to be updated for the changes done in the library with both v1 and v2 SDK, and Lambda functions using them must not be affected.

In Summary:
This library includes one class that uses AWS SDK V1 and another class that uses AWS SDK V2. Additionally, there is another library that uses this library but it only uses the class from AWS SDK V2.
**I'm trying to exclude AWS SDK V1 from dependency while including AWS SDK V2. Is this possible?**

The reason why I am trying to do this is to reduce the latency of the lambda functions because it's loading extra and unnecessary dependencies. If one class is using AWS SDK v1 as it's dependency and I use the library that contains this class as dependency, will SDK V1 still get loaded into the dependency and affect the load time even if the library doesn't utilize that particular class?